# react-intl FormattedMessage not updating after registering reduxForm

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form, react-intl

After registering component with `reduxForm`, `react-intl` `FormattedMessages` are not updating after locale change in state:

```
import React from 'react';
import { reduxForm } from 'react-redux-form';
import { Form } from 'reactstrap';
import { FormattedMessage } from 'react-intl';

const ExampleForm = ({ handleSubmit }) => (
  <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
    <h2>
      <FormattedMessage id="example.title" />
    </h2>
    ...
  </Form>
);

// When added reduxForm FormattedMessages are not displaying
// correct translation after language locale change through reducer
export default reduxForm({
  form: 'example',
})(ExampleForm);

// If I I am using without reduxForm everything works correctly
// export default ExampleForm;
```

Does anyone have experience with this? For me they update only when I leave route and return or just refresh the page of course as I am writing my locale to `localStorage` in actions and reading it in store initializing.

Lib versions:

```
"react": "^16.3.2",
"redux": "^4.0.0",
"react-redux": "^5.0.7",
"redux-form": "^7.3.0",
"react-intl": "^2.4.0",
"react-intl-redux": "^0.7.0",
```

Answer (score 0):

`injectIntl` is needed to wrap `reduxForm`:

```
import { FormattedMessage, injectIntl } from 'react-intl';

export default injectIntl(reduxForm({
  form: 'example',
})(ExampleForm));
```